# Class PDO Not Found - Just upgraded to PHP 5.6 (Debian Wheezy)

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, pdo

I've been away from Laravel/Unix for some time but I have a project to setup and hit some snags. The most recent version of Laravel required PHP >=5.6 so I got that updated, setup my new project with `laravel new project` and made some modifications to the user/group permissions for storage/ and bootstrap/cache folders as normal.

I'm getting HTTP/500 error from Nginx so I checked the error log and I'm getting this in /var/log/nginx/error.log:

**FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Message: PHP Fatal Error: Class PDO not found in /home/user/public_html/project/config/database.php on line 16" while reading upstream ... upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"**

**PHP Version 5.6.28-1~dotdeb+7.1**

When I check /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini the normal `extension=pdo.so` and `extension=pdo_mysql.so` were not there so I added them to test it, however those are being requested in the `conf.d` folder and PHPINO shows those files being scanned/loaded.

**However, later in PHPINFO results, PDO/PDO_MYSQL is not listed**

**UPDATE**

I just attempted to use `find /-name pdo.so` and the same for pdo_mysql.so to find the path to those files and manually modified the loading configuration files to point to them correctly, started the server and that doesn't change anything.

I apologize this is long. I've spent a couple hours scouring to make sure I wasn't just missing something silly, and I may still be.

Any ideas overlfowers?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after much consternation and fiddling I figured this one out...

There was a recursive / endless loop being created in the `php-fpm.conf` config as shown here:

**include=/etc/php5/fpm/*.conf**

This was causing PHP5-FPM .conf to attempt including itself, which I caught in a bootup error: `Failed to load configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf from /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf`

So I modified that to **include=/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/*.conf** and everything started back up and now PDO/PDO_MSYQL is loading.